# cannot mount a virtual drive in centos 7

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, raid, mount

I have a centos 7 which is installed in a RAID1 disks. I have another Raid6 disks which I would like to mount in the system.

when I do `fdisk -l`

the Raid 6 shows as:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 40000.0 GB, 39999997214720 bytes, 78124994560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

but when I try

```
mount /dev/sdb /home/shared_
```

I get

```
mount: /dev/sdb is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'
```

The same does not happen when I try to use a flash drive for example, which I can easily mount.

Comment: Is this hardware or software RAID? Was a filesystem created on it? Did you set it up?

Comment: it is a hardware RAID, what you mean by filesystem? I only selected the hard drives and created a virtual drive with raid 6

Comment: After setting up RAID, you need to create a filesystem on it with the `mkfs` command. For example, if you want it to be `ext4`, you''ll use the command `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb`. Afterwards, use the command `blkid | grep sdb` and you'll see the filesystem in the last column as `TYPE="ext4"` or whatever filesystem you've chosen. Your mount command will then work.

Comment: @NasirRiley Please make your comment an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Comment is now an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up RAID, you need to create a filesystem on it with the `mkfs` command. For example, if you want it to be `ext4`, you''ll use the command

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
```

Afterwards, use the command:

```
blkid | grep sdb
```

and you'll see the filesystem in the last column as `TYPE="ext4"` or whatever filesystem you've chosen. Your mount command will then work.